# nth-child() or first-child? how to select first AND second child in one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to select the first two list items in an unordered list. I can select the first item thus:

```
ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 beige;
}
```

OR

```
ul li:first-child a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 beige;
}
```

I'd like to select both the first and second line item - how do I do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Without the use of js or `:nth-child` (which I believe is not supported in IE)

```
ul li:first-child, ul li:first-child + li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KNe26/) is a demo tested in IE7

Comment: +1 for `:first-child` and adjacent sibling selector, great for compatibility all the way down to IE7.

Answer (score 63):

For selecting the first and second children, you can use a single `:nth-child()` pseudo-class like so:

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+2) a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 beige;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know about using `a=-1`.

Answer (score 5):

This works in IE9+ but it's not the shortest.  @BoltClock's selector is the shortest solution for IE9+.  I think this one is marginally easier to understand so I'll leave it as an alternative.

```
ul li:first-child a, ul li:nth-child(2) a
{
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 biege;
}
```

Comment: thanks. so I must separate by comma each selector - there is no way to select both in the same selector? I was thinking something along the lines of ul li:nth-child(1,2) a - of course that does not work but I was thinking there may be something similar that does?

Comment: @tvanfosson: With `an + b`, you can simply pass a negative `a` and it'll pick up the first `b` children only. See my answer.

Comment: @BoltClock - I learn something new every day. +1 to you, but I'll leave mine here (after some consideration) as I think it's marginally easier to understand what's happening.

Comment: Indeed, I was this close to clicking undelete on your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet for cross-browser compatibility would be to use jQuery and assign a class to the list item.

- http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/index/

Something like...

```
$( function() {

 $('li').each( function() {
   if( $(this).index() == 1 || $(this).index() == 2 ) {
     $(this).addClass('first_or_second');
   }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.trJobStatus ul{
    width: 500px;
  height:500px;
    float: left;
  }
.trJobStatus ul li{
   width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  list-style:none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:50px;
  font-size:25px;
  }

.trJobStatus ul li:nth-child(1),
.trJobStatus ul li:nth-child(5){
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
 
  <div class="trJobStatus">
  <ul>
<li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

.trJobStatus ul li:nth-child(1),
    .trJobStatus ul li:nth-child(2) {
        color: #fff;
        background-color:#ddd;
    }