# Select first n li elements inside div from enitre page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to select all **n li** elements from entire page using **JQuery**.
For example: From below code i want to select first 2 li element from both the div.

```
<div class="abc">
    <ul>
       <li>link 1</li>
       <li>link 2</li>
       <li>link 3</li>
       <li>link 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="abc">
    <ul>
      <li>link 1</li>
      <li>link 2</li>
      <li>link 3</li>
     <li>link 4</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just realised not tagged CSS. In CSS `div li:nth-child(-n+2)` will select the first 2 li children of each divs ul. [Same as this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8821370/2930477)

Comment: $( "div li" ).first()

Comment: [Same question for CSS solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8821193/2930477)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.abc').each(function(index,el){
    var selectedDiv = $(el).find('li');
   selectedDiv =  selectedDiv.slice(0,2);
})
```

You can check here

http://jsfiddle.net/gn3q6oqu/1/

Answer (score 2):

You may try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6qbdn8so/1/):

```
$('div.abc>ul>li:nth-child(-n+2)').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't select first two li in one statement. For that you have to use different statements like
$( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css("color","black");
$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css("color","black");

Comment: But there is no fix number of `div` elements, it is generated dynamically.

Comment: If div elements are not fix then no problem you can add these lines to your page for first two li elements  ul    $( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css("color","black"); $( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css("color","black");